# Is it possible to calculate bitwise OR just by looking decimal numbers?

Tags: math, logic, puzzle

Is it possible to calculate the **BITWISE OR** value for two numbers just by looking the decimal numbers ( or **without** converting them to binary form)?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is no need to "_convert them to binary form,_" since numbers are _already_ stored as binary representations.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume no. OR is a relation defined on boolean values and not on natural numbers.